# Minimum Cost Steiner Tree lib for Java

Tags: graph, tree, minimum

I need a library for directed graphs that can calculate Minimum Steiner Trees in Java. Any heuristic is fine (in terms of runtime and how close to optimal trees are) for me. Does anyone know of any popular package on Github or other places?

Comment: It would be nice to have this for languages other than Java as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SCIPJack solver that is part of the SCIP Optimization Suite to find an optimal directed Steiner tree:
https://www.scipopt.org/doc/applications/STP/STP_MAIN.php

SCIP also has a Java interface.